# how to write dynamically comma character on function (as parameter)?

Tags: java, string, arguments, parameter-passing

I use MxParser library in my project. 
I have written 3 different ways below. the first two of them work but the third one (which I really want) doesn't work

```
 1) (working)
    Argument x=new Argument("x",2);
    Argument y=new Argument("y",3);
    Argument z=new Argument("z",4);
    Expression e2=new Expression("(y-x)*100",x,y,z);
    String result=String.valueOf(e2.calculate());
    System.out.println("result= "+result);


2) (working)
    HashMap<String, Argument> map4 = function_2(list);
    Entry<String, Argument> next4 = map4.entrySet().iterator().next();
    Argument a = next4.getValue();
    String formula="(A+A)*100";
    Expression e = new Expression(formula,a);
    System.out.println("result= " + e.calculate());


3) (not working)
    HashMap<String, Argument> map4 = function_2(list);
    Entry<String, Argument> next4 = map4.entrySet().iterator().next();
    Argument a = next4.getValue();
    String formula="(A+A)*100";

    String s=","; // This line is Dİfferent

    Expression e = new Expression(formula+s+a); // This is too
    System.out.println("result= " + e.calculate());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you like to do that ? Yo are mixing argument values and source code. So what you ask is not possible. Java precompiles code but if what you do would work it would require runtime compilation.

The Expression constructor is `Expression​(java.lang.String expressionString, PrimitiveElement... elements)` so it accepts a variable number of elements. You can even pass an array of PrimitiveElement instances:

```
Argument[] arguments=new Argument[3];
arguments[0]==new Argument("x",2);
arguments[1]=new Argument("y",3);
arguments[2]=new Argument("z",4);
Expression e = new Expression(formula,arguments);
```

Looks like enough flexibility. Or can you explain why this is not a useful solution in your case.

When retaking your last case:

```
    HashMap<String, Argument> map4 = function_2(list);
    String formula="(A+A)*100";
    Expression e = new Expression(formula,map4.values().toArray(new Argument[0]));
    System.out.println("result= " + e.calculate());
```

Argument... only accepts a sequence of Argument instances or an array of type Argument. `map4.values().toArray(new Argument[0])`converts the values argument list to an array. The argument `new Argument[0]` is just necesasry to return an array of the right type.

Comment: oww thank you very very much its working... @Conffusion

Answer (score 0):

I return dynamic values ​​as a result in a function I write. (for example, A, B and C (all Argument type))

I have to create an expression automatically according to the result from the function.

for example;
for example, if 3 values ​​return (A, B, C)
it should be like this;

```
Expression e2 = new Expression ("(A * B) * (C-100)", A, B, C);
```

if 2 values ​​return (A, B, C)
it should be like this;

```
Expression e2 = new Expression ("(A * B) / 10", A, B);
```

if 1 returns (A)
it should be like this;

```
Expression e2 = new Expression ("(A * 15)", A);
```

that is, I have to write these expressions automatically according to the next number.

then I will calculate with the calculate () function.

Comment: @Conffusion #Conffusion

Comment: so by the time you call the constructor you have the arguments so you can put them in an array and call the constructor with this array as second parameter.

Comment: I couldn't fully understand. Can you give an example @Conffusion

Comment: I've added an example based on your last example. See my answer.

Comment: Are your formulas fixed ? What if you have 4 arguments ?